# How do I determine what "key path" arguments to provide to `prefetch_related` in Django?

Tags: django, prefetch

Note: below, I am going to refer to the arguments supplied to `prefetch_related` as "key paths".  I don't know if that's the best/correct term -  so let me know if there's a better term to use and I will update the question.

I created an advanced search page in django that searches any of a number of fields from 6 different tables (not all of which are single a direct foreign key path) and displays selected fields from all those tables in a results table.  The "key paths" included are:

- `msrun__sample`
- `msrun__sample__tissue`
- `msrun__sample__animal`
- `msrun__sample__animal__tracer_compound`
- `msrun__sample__animal__studies`

*(Note: no msrun fields are included in the search or display.  That specific model class in this particular view only serves as a connection between the model classes involved in the view.)*

It makes a huge difference in the run time when I include a prefetch like: `.prefetch_related("msrun__sample__animal__studies")`, but I see no discernible difference when I include any additional prefetch "key paths".

My question is: How do I determine which "key path" or "key paths" to include in the arguments to `prefetch_related`?  I don't seem to understand the criteria that would go into that decision.  I.e. Why would I or would I not, say, include all the related "key paths" among the `prefetch_related` arguments?

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barket - OK.

Comment: It depends on your use case. But using `msrun__sample__animal__studies` will include all the relations from `msrun` until `studies`. So no need to write the other key paths, as they are already covered by the deepest relation defined (`msrun` -> `studies`). That's why you don't see any difference when you use the other key paths. Note though that using that key path will create 5 queries, one for each level (the main `model`, `msrun`, `sample`, `animal`, and then `studies`)

Comment: I was wondering about whether the contained sub paths provided any advantage. But what about `msrun__sample__animal__tracer_compound`? That wouldn't be included in the one path.

Comment: Is `tracer_compound` a foreign key? If not, it will still be covered until `animal`. If it is, then it needs to be defined in the prefetch as well, if you need the fields of `tracer_compound`.

Comment: Yes, all the "__" delimited items in the provided "key paths" are foreign keys. That one is a key to the Compound table.

Comment: Right. Then in this case, you should just need three key paths: `msrun__sample__tissue`, `msrun__sample__animal__tracer_compound` and `msrun__sample__animal__studies`.

Comment: @bdbd - if you describe this all in an answer, I'll select it. I haven't tried it yet, but I think you're right - and the docs don't go into this explicitly.

Comment: I just checked the docs again, it's in the section of [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) where they used this example: `Restaurant.objects.prefetch_related('best_pizza__toppings')`

Comment: Right - and that's a direct path. I read that and consulted it many times. It doesn't explicitly address branched paths or supplying multiple overlapping key paths. I didn't know whether it would repeat queries where the paths overlap and I could see no discernible difference in speed, but that could just be because my specific data/table-structure wasn't heavy at those branches - so I just wanted to know whether adding those other paths programmatically was going to bite me later with other data.

Comment: Yes great question. I added an answer with some example data for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this out with below models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    my_b_set = models.ManyToManyField('B', related_name='my_a')


class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    my_c_set = models.ManyToManyField('C', related_name='my_b')
    my_d_set = models.ManyToManyField('D', related_name='my_c')


class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class D(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And filled the relationships like so:

```
a = A.objects.create(name='a1')
b1 = B.objects.create(name='b1')
b2 = B.objects.create(name='b2')
c1 = C.objects.create(name='c1')
c2 = C.objects.create(name='c2')
d1 = D.objects.create(name='d1')
d2 = D.objects.create(name='d2')

a.my_b_set.add(b1)
a.my_b_set.add(b2)

b1.my_c_set.add(c1, c2)
b1.my_d_set.add(d1, d2)

b2.my_c_set.add(c1, c2)
b2.my_d_set.add(d1, d2)
```

Then run this query:

```
A.objects.prefetch_related('my_b_set', 'my_b_set__my_c_set', 'my_b_set__my_d_set')
```

As expected, it made 4 queries:

```
-- Get all A's

SELECT "changelog_a"."id", "changelog_a"."name" FROM "changelog_a"


-- Get all the related B's of A mapped with A's id

SELECT ("changelog_a_my_b_set"."a_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_a_id", "changelog_b"."id", "changelog_b"."name" 
FROM "changelog_b" INNER JOIN "changelog_a_my_b_set" ON ("changelog_b"."id" = "changelog_a_my_b_set"."b_id") 
WHERE "changelog_a_my_b_set"."a_id" IN (2)


-- Get all the related C's of B mapped with B's id

SELECT ("changelog_b_my_c_set"."b_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_b_id", "changelog_c"."id", "changelog_c"."name" 
FROM "changelog_c" INNER JOIN "changelog_b_my_c_set" ON ("changelog_c"."id" = "changelog_b_my_c_set"."c_id") 
WHERE "changelog_b_my_c_set"."b_id" IN (3, 4)


-- Get all the related D's of B mapped with B's id

SELECT ("changelog_b_my_d_set"."b_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_b_id", "changelog_d"."id", "changelog_d"."name" 
FROM "changelog_d" INNER JOIN "changelog_b_my_d_set" ON ("changelog_d"."id" = "changelog_b_my_d_set"."d_id") 
WHERE "changelog_b_my_d_set"."b_id" IN (3, 4)
```

So in this example, overlapping key paths with new relations would not repeat the queries for B, and will only create new queries for those new relations.